# How do you load videos from a local folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you load videos from a local folder?

I have tried using UnityWebRequest.

```
private void Start()
{
    path = @"C:/Users/" + System.Environment.UserName + @"/Videos/";
    files = Directory.GetFiles(@path, "*.mp4", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    LoadVideo();
}

private void LoadVideo()
{
    pathPrefix = @"file:///";
    fullFileName = pathPrefix + files[0];
    WWW www = new WWW(fullFileName);
    MovieTexture movieToPlay = www.GetMovieTexture();
    image.texture = movieToPlay;
    movieToPlay.Play();
}
```

I expected it to render the video on the raw image.
But the raw image is just transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the videos being imported? Can you add a Debug.Log() to check if the video is being added along with the name and extension .mp4. You are using movieTexture to play the video, try to create a quad and add video player and this script to it. Instead of movieTexture, use quad's material to play the video. More to follow:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html

Comment: Please provide an upvote if this helped you. Thanks ;)